# How to call a Sub with KeyEventArgs from another Sub

Tags: vb.net, events, call, keyboard-events, keyevent

I have two subs

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles KeyHook.KeyDown
```

and

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPressCaps(ByVal key As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.CapsLock Then
        If keyStCL = True Then

            checkbutton_caps.Checked = False
            checkbutton_caps.Image = My.Resources.Resource1.btn_ico_caps_off
            'Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_off.png")
            keyStCL = False

        ElseIf keyStCL = False Then
            checkbutton_caps.Checked = True
            checkbutton_caps.Image = My.Resources.Resource1.btn_ico_caps_on
            'Image.FromFile("resources\btn_ico_caps_on.png")
            keyStCL = True

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to call Form1_KeyPressCaps from kbHook_KeyDown. How do I do it.
I tried this:

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles KeyHook.KeyDown
    Call Form1_KeyPressCaps(Key, New KeyEventArgs)
End Sub
```

But its not working. I am getting an error:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'keyData' of 'Public Sub New(keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)'.

Comment: What is confusing you?  keydata is a required parameter to create a KeyEventArgs instance. the error says so

Comment: @Plutonix 
Form1_KeyPressCaps is used to handle Key Down event of the Caps Lock key. So how should I specify the argument for keydata?

Comment: Just pass the `Key` variable to your new `KeyEventArgs` class. You should know how to pass parameters/arguments since you're already doing so, if not, do read up on it: [**How to: Pass Arguments to a Procedure (Visual Basic)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d4hzxt6.aspx). -- Also you should remove the `Call` keyword. It is superfluous.

Comment: There is just no point to that.  Write a Sub CapsKeyChanged and move the code into it.  Now it is just as easy to call from your KeyDown event handler as your other code and it is more readable and understandable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles KeyHook.KeyDown
    Call Form1_KeyPressCaps(Key, New KeyEventArgs(Key))
End Sub
```

Comment: This works in WindowsForm. How does this work in WPF?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#examples is an example of similar functionality in WPF.